# C# directory search (the number)

Tags: c#, directory

```
private int dReturn, fReturn = 0;

public Maker()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (fd.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) { return; }
    listView1.Items.Clear();
    dReturn = 0;
    fReturn = 0;
    textBox1.Text = fd.SelectedPath;

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner();

    scanner.Show();
    fscan(fd.SelectedPath);
    dscan(fd.SelectedPath);
    scanner.Close();

    MessageBox.Show("File : " + fReturn + ", Folder : " + dReturn, "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}

private int dscan(string path)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
        {
            dReturn = dReturn + 1;
            dscan(d);
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
    }

    catch(Exception)
    {
        ListViewItem access = new ListViewItem(path);
        listView1.Items.Add(access);
    }

    return dReturn;
}
```

I want know number of folders in selected path.
So I made a recursive function as above.
But The number of folders not the same as PC property view.
Please Help me...
Fine when the path is small, the problem arises when large.

---

Thanks for your comment.
Sorry, It was Not enough description.
I show you some image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpqH0.png)

like this my program search more number of folder.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996443/number-of-folder-inside-a-directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you have some hidden folders ([C# - Get a list of files excluding those that are hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418270/c-sharp-get-a-list-of-files-excluding-those-that-are-hidden)) ?

By the way, GetDirectories can return all subdirectories : https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms143314(v=vs.110).aspx :

```
Directory.GetDirectories(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

If you still have problems, try debugging to see the differences.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I add my description. Please confirm once more. sorry i'm bad english

Comment: As already said, it could be explained by hidden files and folders or access rights : try launching your application with admin rights to see if it gives a different result.

Comment: Modify your `dscan` function this way : `foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(path).Where(folder => !folder.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Hidden)))` and see if the result matches the explorer one.

Comment: I did it. The results came out too small value. Real folders number is 830. And my program search only 32 folders. :(